# How to prevent Cypress v10 from writing the file "index.js" into the directory "cypress/plugins" on test execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

The Cypress configuration of our project is in a custom folder called `src/` instead of the default folder `cypress/`. The file `index.ts` can be found in the directory `src/support/`

This setup works alright, however, on each test-execution Cypress automatically saves a folder called `cypress/` with the contents `download/(empty)` and `plugins/index.js`. I assume that this means that there's something wrong in the `cypress.config.js`:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  (...)
    e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {},
    supportFile: './src/support/index.ts',
    integrationFolder: "./src/integration",
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4400'
  }
})
```

This is the file structure:

[image]

What do I need to change to stop this?

Comment: You can move the downloads folder by setting `downloadsFolder`: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files. But the whole `plugins/` directory is replaced by `setupNodeEvents` in Cypress 10. Can you give a [mre], maybe there are other libraries/plugins involved that are doing this? If you explicitly set the `pluginsFile` option does that change anything (Cypress _may_ validate and reject this, I haven't tried)?

Comment: A couple of other notes - there's no such configuration key as `integrationFolder` in Cypress 10, so that's not useful, in fact it should even be causing an error. The main issue may be due to `storybook` which tends to be a bit opinionated - have you used a version that's not compatible with Cypress 10?